# Bridge Movie Night - April 2016

Tags: discussion, community, community-event

February had some great attendance and some nice conversation during the movie, let's hope that will carry into April. Remember, you have the whole month to vote on scheduling and movie selection since Movie Night isn't until April.

[Movie Night Scheduling Poll](http://strawpoll.me/6975487)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Movie Decision

[image]

## Office Space

As always, we will be watching the movie together on [Rabbit](https://rabb.it/yuuki). Movie Night will be taking place on Saturday, April 2nd beginning at 11:00pm UTC-0. Do be aware that this is only a rough estimate of the start time, we may begin later than announced or we might not.

In addition, Saturday is only the official Movie Night showing. If you cannot make it to the Saturday showing, you can come into [The Bridge chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) on Sunday and request a showing. I will do my best to accommodate you.

Answer (score 16):

[image: If we could be watching Office Space, it would be grrreat.]

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeah, I'm going to need you to go ahead and come in on Saturday.

Comment: [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/office_space/?search=office%20space), [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0151804), the trailer is spoilerrific so no link. 89 mins.

Comment: Excuse me, I believe you have my stapler...

Comment: What would you say... ya do here?

Answer (score 3):

## Movie Suggestion: Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens

[image: Movie Poster]

Three decades after the defeat of the Galactic Empire, a new threat arises. The First Order attempts to rule the galaxy and only a ragtag group of heroes can stop them, along with the help of the Resistance.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGbxmsDFVnE) | [Rotten Tomatoes (93%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/star_wars_episode_vii_the_force_awakens/) | [IMDB 8.4 (Rated PG-13)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/)

Comment: i would have to watch all 6 of the other movies by then to be able to watch this.

Comment: You don't, you only need to see five.  [Watch them in the machete order](http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2011/11/11/the-star-wars-saga-suggested-viewing-order/), IV, V, II, III, VI, or skip the prequels entirely.

Comment: And honestly, if you know who Luke, Leia, Han, and Chewie are, you'll be fine,.

Comment: Confirmed digital release on April 1, so this is greenlighted for this month's Movie Night.

Comment: @Yuuki, how do you know this? Is there a Romanian version? I hope the Romanian audio version is released, I saw it in the cinema the other day at the cinema, it was amazing! It was as though the film had been shot in Romanian. I was talking to some people that work at a dvd distribution company and they were saying that there was no chance of a Romanian version being released, ii hope that they are wrong.

Comment: Got an email from Disney confirming a digital release on April. DVDs are physical.

Comment: [The movie is out and are on _some_ websites already.](https://0ws.pw/hxl5.png)

Answer (score 0):

## Movie Suggestion

[image: Chef]

Jon Favreau plays Carl Gasper, a gifted chef who's unhappy with his job at one of LA's trendiest restaurants cooking the same food over and over again. After getting a scathing review from a top food critic, Gasper quits his job and travels to Miami to run a food truck.

Warning: do not watch this movie on an empty stomach as there is copious amounts of food.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK-ZUFX5fnk) | [Rotten Tomatoes (86%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/chef_2014/) | [Parental Guide (Rated R for food porn)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2883512/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg)

Comment: Great Choice! Saw this in theaters as a Selected Pre-Screening in my town. It really does play to foodies though.

Comment: I wonder why I'm not surprised to see Yuuki post a movie that is about food.

Answer (score 0):

## Movie Suggestion: Predestination

[image: Movie Poster]

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FcK_UiVV40) | [Rotten Tomatoes (84%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/predestination/) | [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2397535/) | [Parental Guide (15)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2397535/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg#certification)